# Browser-sync Cannot GET /

Tags: html, node.js, ubuntu, synchronization, browser-sync

I just installed browser-sync but when I try to start a server I get this error:

```
      terkea@terkea-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ browser-sync start --server --files index.html[Browsersync] Access URLs:
```

---

```
   Local: http://localhost:3000
External: http://192.168.1.3:3000
------------------------------------
      UI: http://localhost:3001
UI External: http://192.168.1.3:3001
------------------------------------
```

[Browsersync] Serving files from: ./
    [Browsersync] Watching files...

Maybe someone could find what's wrong and help me please?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: when i open the browser i get CANNOT GET/ instead of my index.php

Comment: I don't get that, and please add the error to your question instead of commenting it

Comment: did u ever use browser-sync?

Comment: Yes, I did. But I do not get what you did to provoke the error.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to pass an argument to --server which is the directory from which you want to serve the files from. Browser-sync uses your current working directory by default.

So for example, if you're starting browser-sync in the root directory of your project, and your index.html is in folder a/b/c/index.html, then the browser-sync command will be:

```
browser-sync start --server "a/b/c/" --files "index.html"
```

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the folder in which your files are located. I use ubuntu 18.04 and it works.
For example, if you want to open all files in directory /home/user/code you must write this command:

```
browser-sync start --server "/home/user/code/" --files "*.*"
```

Comment: *UPD:* a small correction - works correctly only if you advance to the project's layout and start the program from there.
example: 
`cd /home/user/code
browser-sync start --server  --files "*.*"`

Answer (score 0):

I just used browser-sync for the first time and experienced the same problem. I was expecting it to serve a directory listing like `http-server` does but that only happens if you add the `--directory` flag. Otherwise if you want it to open a specific file then specify it with `--index`.

- `browser-sync start --server --directory` serves a directory listing
- `browser-sync start --server --index "test.html"` serves `test.html`