# Browsersync IDE error "Couldn't open browser (if you are using BrowserSync in a headless environment, you might want to set the open option to false)"

Tags: javascript, browser, ide, headless, browser-sync

I'm stuck on lesson 19 of this course - https://javascript30.com/ - which uses Browsersync to provide access to the webcam.

These are the files I'm working with: https://github.com/wesbos/JavaScript30/tree/master/19%20-%20Webcam%20Fun

Having run `npm install` I get this error when trying to run the package that includes [Browsersync](https://www.browsersync.io/) and none of the URLs below work for me:

```
~/JavaScript30-master/JavaScript30-master/19 - Webcam Fun/ $ npm start

> gum@1.0.0 start /home/ubuntu/JavaScript30-master/JavaScript30-master/19 - Webcam Fun
> browser-sync start --server --files "*.css, *.html, *.js"

[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 ---------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.35.240:3000
 ---------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://192.168.35.240:3001
 ---------------------------------------
[Browsersync] Serving files from: ./
[Browsersync] Watching files...
[Browsersync] Couldn't open browser (if you are using BrowserSync in a headless environment, you might want to set the open option to false)
```

I'm using [an IDE](https://ide.cs50.io/) that I've stuck with since doing [Harvard's CS50 course](https://cs50.harvard.edu/college/2021/spring/) in Chrome [Version 91.0.4472.77 (Official Build) (64-bit)] on a DELL laptop running 64-bit Windows 10 Enterprise. Also tried using Brave [Version 1.25.70 Chromium: 91.0.4472.77 (Official Build) (64-bit)].

I've checked [Browsersync docs](https://www.browsersync.io/docs), searched the web, YouTube and Browsersync Slack, and looked at the following:

1. [Browser-sync Cannot GET /](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47739849/browser-sync-cannot-get)
2. [browser-sync not working with single page application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41232559/browser-sync-not-working-with-single-page-application)
3. [BrowserSync Gulp doesn't open in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47430871/browsersync-gulp-doesnt-open-in-chrome)
4. [Browsersync "browser" option in Ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47984484/browsersync-browser-option-in-ubuntu-16-04)
5. [BROWSER SYNC headless environment ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44432953/browser-sync-headless-environment-error)
6. https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/wiki/Working-with-a-Config-File

I'm still quite new to coding and suddenly feel very out of my depth!

Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CS50 IDE provides a "cloud-based Ubuntu environment", but that means "localhost" according to the browsersync output you're seeing isn't ***your*** localhost ― it's the localhost of that cloud environment.

(And the "External" direct IP access will be incorrect too, since it references a local network that your computer isn't attached to.)

The IDE might provide a way for you to access a server that's running in this way, but I suspect a simpler path is to run the `start` script directly on your local machine.